# Constructing Mixins

Tags: python

This may be a very basic OOP question:

I have 2 class that aren't in the same hierarchy. But both classes have some methods that are identical in its code. Those methods implement the "UI" of their classes. I am planning to move those methods into a mixin, and have both classes inherit that mixin.

Problem is: those methods currently need to refer to attributes of their classes (because they are essentially UI's of the class): eg: they both refer to `self.MyVar()`, which is defined differently in class A and class B.

How can I construct my mixin in this case?

Comment: Does Python have Reflection?  You could reflect over any members that you may need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mixin can call `self.MyVar()` even if doesn't implement it, the inheriting object's implementation will be used (first):

```
class Mixin(object):
    def talk(self):
        print self.get_message()

class Inheritor(Mixin):
    def get_message(self):
        return "I'm inheriting"

i = Inheritor()
i.talk()
# prints "I'm inheriting"
```

This would work even if `Mixin` implemented `get_message`, by the way.

Every time you do `self.something()`, Python will look up `something` in the order defined by the class' "Method Resolution Order":

```
print Inheritor.__mro__
(<class '__main__.Inheritor'>, <class '__main__.Mixin'>, <type 'object'>)
```

Comment: Ah that's useful. Is that something unique to Python, or a just a general OOP concept?

Comment: @user1008636 Really depends on the language. AFAIK, that wouldn't work in Go, for example.

Comment: Python's a bit unusual in that classes can call methods not defined anywhere in their own inheritance hierarchies, but any language with reflection capabilities can do this to some degree (and some without reflection can simply emulate it with e.g. an appropriate interface).